# How do i get rid of a power-spike from consumer electronics?

Tags: power-supply, current

Ive got a power-spike (im guessing here) when the amplification stage in a  speaker turns on, that temporarily disables my tv (black screen, but recovers in a second) and my question is how do i get rid of it? The speaker actively turns on its amplification (with an audible "click")  when it recieves a signal above a certain level.

- Would a ferrite bead anywhere help?
- Is it a grounding issue?
- Should i attack the power lines, or is it related to signal cables?
- Solder larger caps in the speakers power-supply? (not so accessible)

[image]

Comment: Throw away the broken device?

Comment: Ferrite bead: that's not going to help, ferrite bead only "do" something at RF and that is not the issue here I believe. Larger caps will probably make things **worse**. Try powering the Active speaker from a different mains group, try with a long extension cord if you must.

Comment: there's something wrong with your TV, could be the capacitors in its powersupply need replacing.

Comment: How exactly do you plan to attack the power lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible causes, with a bonus one:

1- Speaker does evil things to mains voltage

2- Speaker sends common mode noise into signal cables, which zaps the TV.

3- Speaker radiates enough EMI through the air to reboot the TV (unlikely)

To distinguish, unplug the audio cables from the speaker, it shouldd now be only connected to the mains. Feed it some music from an ungrounded device like an iPod/phone/whatever, or just put a cable in the RCA and stick your finger on the center pin at the other end, that will create enough BUZZZZZ to make the speaker think there is signal and it should turn on.

If the TV does not reboot, then cause 2 should be suspected.

If the TV reboots while the speaker is connected only to the mains (no other cables) then this rules out cause 2.

Now use an extension cord to connect the speaker to the mains, but still in the same socket. Repeat. Most likely the TV still reboots.

Move the speaker away (that's why you put an extension cord), repeat.

TV still reboots, that rules out cause 3 "airborne EMI" which was unlikely anyway.

Connect the extension cord to another outlet away in the house. Repeat.

If TV does not reboot, then the speaker does have an inrush current or other mains borne EMI problem, or the outlet your TV is plugged in has high resistance, oxidized old wires and the like.

To be continued after you perform the tests...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I will try all you troubleshooting tips. Marking as answer for now

Answer (score 0):

It's definitelly a power storage problem, either a cap in your TV or in your amp is broken and needs to be replaced. Another solution would be to put the amplifier on another phase than your TV, but I doubt you have more than one phase installed in that room. By doing that, the amp would draw the current from another AC phase and not affect your TV.